# How can I plot 2 <= z <= 5 in a 3D graph?

Tags: plotting

How can I plot 2 <= z <= 5 in a 3D graph?
Also, how can I plot only two variables in a 3D graph. For example x = 2, y = 3.
I've been using CountourPlot3D and other help but cannot resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

`Plot3D` with `Filling` is another way.

```
Clear;
z1 = 2;
z2 = 5;
Plot3D[{z2, z1}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, Filling -> {1 -> z1}, 
 FillingStyle -> Yellow, PlotStyle -> {Red, None}, Mesh -> False, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

To Plot $x=2,y=3$, we can regard it as a parametric curve according to `z`

```
ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, z} /. {x -> 2, y -> 3}, {z, -5, 5}, 
 PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}]
```

[image]

To Plot $x=2$ and $y=3$, we can also regard it as the intersection of two surface $x=2$ and $y=3$ and then use the tricks of `Mesh` and `MeshFunctions`.

```
ContourPlot3D[y == 3, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}, 
 ContourStyle -> None, MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z}, x - 2], 
 Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> {Red, Thick}, BoundaryStyle -> None]
```

[image]

**Appendix**

For sufficient simple situation,we can use `Region` and `ImplicitRegion` do the job as mention by @user64494 in the comment.

```
a = Region[
   ImplicitRegion[{x == 2 && y == 3}, {{x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5,
       5}}], BaseStyle -> Red];
b = Region[
   ImplicitRegion[
    x == 2 || y == 3 , {{x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}}], 
   BaseStyle -> Blue];
c = Region[
   ImplicitRegion[y == 3, {{x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}}], 
   BaseStyle -> Cyan];
d = Region[ImplicitRegion[2 <= z <= 5, {x, y, z}], 
   BaseStyle -> Orange];
Grid[{{a, b}, {c, d}}]
```

[image]

Comment: `InfiniteLine` and `InfinitePlane` also  work.

Answer (score 0):

Try `RegionPlot3D`

```
RegionPlot3D[2 <= z <= 5, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, 0, 10}]
```

`RegionPlot3D` shows only three-dimensional subregions. To answer your second, try something like ``

```
RegionPlot3D[1.5 < x < 2.5 && 2.5 < y < 3.5, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}  ]
```

Comment: Thank you Ulrich Neumann

Comment: Or combine plots: `Show[RegionPlot3D[2 <= z <= 5, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, {z, 0, 7}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.75]],
 ContourPlot3D[{x == 2, y == 3}, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, {z, 0, 7}, ContourStyle -> {Blue, Red}],
 AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]`

Comment: You 're welcome.

Comment: I'm new to Mathematica and really appreciate this.

Comment: `Region[ImplicitRegion[z >= 2 && z <= 5, {x, y, z}]]` is another possibility.